# unexpected EOF error in JS

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, genetic-algorithm, eof

Im working on this piece of code for a genetic algorithm, but when i run this code i keep getting an unexpected EOF error right after the draw function.

> SyntaxError: Expected eof but found }

im not very good at javascript so i dont know if i made a stupid mistake or something. It seemed to work fine until i changed something? i dont know but it doesnt work anymore, maybe i just dont see it...

```
var population;
var lifespan = 200;
var lifeP;
var count = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,300);
  rocket = new Rocket();
  population = new Population();
  lifeP = createP();
}

function draw() {
  background(0); 
  population.run();
  lifeP.html(count);
  count++;
}

function Population() {
 this.rockets = [];
 this.popsize = 25;


 for(var i = 0; i < this.popsize; i++){
  this.rockets[i] = new Rocket(); 
 }

 this.run = function() {
   for(var i = 0; i < this.popsize; i++){
    this.rockets[i].update();
    this.rockets[i].show();
   }
 }
}


function DNA(){
 this.genes = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < lifespan; i++){
   this.genes[i] = p5.Vector.random2D();
   this.genes[i].setMag(0.1);
 }
}

function Rocket(){
 this.pos = createVector(width/2, height);
 this.vel = createVector();
 this.acc = createVector();
 this.dna = new DNA();;
 this.applyForce = function(force){
  this.acc.add(force);   
 }

 this.update = function(){
  this.applyForce(this.dna.genes[count]);

  this.vel.add(this.acc);
  this.pos.add(this.vel);
  this.acc.mult(0);
 }

 this.show = function(){
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 150);
  translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y); 
  rotate(this.vel.heading());
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(0, 0, 25, 5);
  pop();
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rocket class should look like this:

```js
function Rocket(){
 this.pos = createVector(width/2, height);
 this.vel = createVector();
 this.acc = createVector();
 this.dna = new DNA();
 this.applyForce = function(force){
  this.acc.add(force);   
 }

 this.update = function(){
  this.applyForce(this.dna.genes[count]);

  this.vel.add(this.acc);
  this.pos.add(this.vel);
  this.acc.mult(0);
 }

 this.show = function(){
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 150);
  translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y); 
  rotate(this.vel.heading());
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(0, 0, 25, 5);
  pop();
 }
}
```

But for the next time, check your code in a editor like
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and don't spam stackoverflow